# Change interval of an IntervalObservable using a variable

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, angular2-observables

I have a component that should execute some code at intervals without stopping. Im using an IntervalObservable and at some point i need to change its interval. I can change the variable value using the setTime() function but the observable keeps running with the same interval since its creation (behaviour that I understand), but I have no clue what to do in order to make the observable change its value. 
Thanks in advance.

**Component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './graphs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./graphs.component.css']
})
export class GraphsComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedTime:number
  selectedRefresh=10

constructor() {

IntervalObservable.create(this.selectedRefresh*1000).subscribe(n => {
//DO THINGS
});
 }

 setTime() {

    this.selectedRefresh = selectedTime*60/(0.3*100)

  }
```

**html**

```
<form (keyup.enter)="setTime()"><input type="number" [(ngModel)]="selectedTime"  name="time" placeholder="enter mins" ngModel/></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't change the interval. You are going to have to unsubscribe from the observable, and then create a new one, and subscribe to that.